# Force changes from the outside to propagate into the container

Tags: docker, bind-mount

I have a Docker container based on the [`gitlab-ce/latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) image. In order to allow certain additional operations with Ansible while being minimally invasive, I opted to [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) over the `/assets/sshd_config` which comes with the container by default. I could have opted for copying or `docker compose`, but I ended up doing it this way.

The resulting mount looks as follows (`docker inspect` excerpt):

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/srv/gitlab/sshd_config",
        "Target": "/assets/sshd_config",
        "ReadOnly": true,
        "BindOptions": {
            "Propagation": "shared"
        }
    }
],
```

Now I noticed that changes to the file made on the host side (`/srv/gitlab/sshd_config`) are not reflected inside the container (`/assets/sshd_config`) unless I restart the container.

Is there a way to make host side changes immediately visible inside the container without extensive changes or having to *restart* the container?

Answer (score 0):

A bind mount should be *present* inside the container, however sshd will not read a new configuration until it's restarted.

### Step 1 - Get the container name

```bsh
$ docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                                 PORTS                      NAMES                                            
b1605793904b        gitlab/gitlab-ce      "/assets/wrapper"        About a minute ago   Up About a minute (health: starting)   22/tcp, 80/tcp, 443/tcp    elastic_austin
```

In this case my container was given the name "elastic_austin"

### Step 2 (optional) - Determine if the files you modified are present

You can check that your changes are present from bash inside the container with `docker exec`

```bsh
$ docker exec -it elastic_austin bash
root@b1605793904b:/# tail /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[...your sshd_config here...]
```

Hopefully your changes should be there.

### Step 3 - Restart the SSH daemon

Now that we know the changes are inside your container, you need to restart the sshd service inside the container.

You can run `service ssh restart` from bash inside the container, or run it with `docker exec` from the host.

```bsh
$ docker exec -it elastic_austin service ssh restart
 * Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                [ OK ]
```

That should force the container to reload the updated ssh configuration.

Comment: thanks for answering, as stated in my question the changes are not reflected inside the container. Restarting the `sshd` won't help if the changes aren't in the `sshd_config` file in question. Somehow a bind-mounted file behaves differently from a volume (a directory which is mounted into the container). For the latter it works, but that requires a directory to be defined as volume and creates a catch 22 situation for me (without a started container I have no way of getting the contents of the directory to copy them out, manipulate them and then define the volume).

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly you defined the bind-mount of an outside `sshd_config` into the container? It should be part of step 0, I guess. But it's missing.

Comment: Oh, whoops -- I'm not familiar with the gitlab-ce image. I gave instructions for dealing with the default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but you're modifying `/assets/sshd_config`. I assume you checked the file at the correct location (step 2 `tail /assets/sshd_config`). Per your `docker inspect` command it seems to share just fine for me. `docker run -d --rm --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/gitlab/sshd_config,destination=/assets/sshd_config,bind-propagation=shared,readonly gitlab/gitlab-ce` I'm not sure why you need to set the bind-propagation instead of leaving it with the default `rprivate`, though.